# What does the ellipse in Gradient descent describes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I saw multiple articles describes `GD` or `SGD` with the following diagram:
[image]

I didn't saw any explanation about the ellipses.

1. What does each ellipse describe ?
2. What is the meaning if the ellipse has large or small diameter ?
3. Does the wights (which are the ellipse in the image) must has the ellipse shape ? (Are there any other shapes you can show as an example) ?

Comment: The plot depicts level sets of loss values along the vertical and horizontal directions. Sometimes it’s called a contour set. The basic idea is that it’s not possible to draw a three-dimensional diagram (the ink would need to come out of the page) but we can try and reproduce the general idea with level sets.

Comment: When the objective function is continuously second differentiable and positive-definite at a local minimum, the contours will be as close to perfect ellipses as you like provided you zoom in far enough.  This is a special case of a basic theorem of multivariable Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The ellipses are contours where the loss function is constant. This type of plot is usually known as "contour plot". The shape of ellipses is due to the loss surface, and any other shape could be possible.